Use python to take a screenshot of background app/window
I'm trying to write python code that captures screenshots and write the captured text to a text file. I did that by specifying a certain region for the screenshot and it works fine. But I would rather somehow specify how to capture a specific window. Even if that window is moved around during the process or is in the background.
Is there a way to do this?
I'm using MacOS
Here is my code so far:
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import schedule
import time


region = (71, 524, 1356, 823) 
# Output file
output_file = 'captured_text.txt'
last_text = ""

def capture_and_recognize():
    global last_text

    # Capture the specified region of the screen
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=region)
    
    # Perform OCR on the captured image
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(screenshot, lang='eng', config='--psm 6').strip()
    
    # Compare with the last captured text
    if text and text != last_text:
        # Append recognized text to the output file
        with open(output_file, 'a') as f:
            f.write(text + '\n')
        
        print(f"Captured Text: {text}")
        last_text = text

# Schedule the capture function to run every 0.5 seconds
schedule.every(0.5).seconds.do(capture_and_recognize)

print("Starting text capture... Press Ctrl+C to stop.")
try:
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(0.1)  
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Text capture stopped.")


Maybe you could use the PyGetWindow library to get the window's position (and size) and use it together with pyscreenshot to capture the screenshot.

from what i found, getWindowsWithTitle of PyGetWindow doesn't work on Mac, sadly

as I know ImageGrab is a wrapper on some C/C++ programs which get screenshot. On Linux it uses program scrot which can get screenshot of window but it has to be on top and it has to be active.
